# How can I send blend file data with Python Pickle?

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files

I want to send objects across the interwebs,starting with the default cube.
Python pickle can send binary packets across connections, so this shouldn't be too hard, just a read in that seems the most confusing.

1. How does one grab binary data from a .blend file?
2. How does one grab binary data from memory? Is there a python binding for this? 
   If I can do read, chances are write is similar.

Potential uses: send your best friend your default cube, colored , textured, with images and cool stuff attached to it,with all the modifiers too.

Comment: Do you want to send the data from the .blend or from an external file? A bit more information would be appreciated.

Comment: default cube saved as a .blend , open this up in blender and you now have the default cube instance in memory, and a default cube in the blend. I want to modify the cube (chance a vertex) on the instance in memory, then send the binary data over a socket connection to a listener, that will reconstruct the binary data and put it into my scene. Kindof like a start trek transporter, only simpler. I suppose if I can find the instance in memory, I can use that info to read the blend file externally... the memory one seems to be easier to think about though.